# Request handler not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, event-handling, request

Clicking my link to login/logout, it works correctly (reloads the page, updating the link text).

I also have a request handler which sends me an email with the value of a submitted form's input, then loads the same page. It also seems to be working correctly (I received the email, showing the correct value).

Problem is, if I click that same login/logout AFTER submitting the form, it doesn't work. It does take me to the login page, but then finally to a blank screen. It shows the url for my app in the address bar, but everything else is just white.

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import wsgiref.handlers

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import mail

class Greeting(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty()
    duties = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class e_mail(db.Model):
     address = db.StringProperty()

def guestbook_key(guestbook_name= users.get_current_user()):
    return db.Key.from_path('Guestbook', guestbook_name or 'default_guestbook')

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        guestbook_name=self.request.get('guestbook_name')
        greetings_query = Greeting.all().ancestor(
        guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order('-date')
        greetings = greetings_query.fetch(1000)
        nickname = None

        if users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'LOGOUT'

            template_values = {
                'greetings': greetings,
                'url': url,
                'url_linktext': url_linktext,
            }

            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'about.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'LOGIN'

            template_values = {
                'greetings': greetings,
                'url': url,
                'url_linktext': url_linktext,
            }

            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'about.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values)) 

class Email_SignUp(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        guestbook_name=self.request.get('guestbook_name')
        greetings_query = Greeting.all().ancestor(
        guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order('-date')
        greetings = greetings_query.fetch(1000)
        nickname = None

        if users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'LOGOUT'

            template_values = {
                'greetings': greetings,
                'url': url,
                'url_linktext': url_linktext,
            }

            e_mail.address = self.request.get('emailAdd')

            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'about.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

            mail.send_mail(sender="Do Not Reply <myemail@address.com>",
                       to="Do Not Reply <myemail@address.com>",
                       subject=e_mail.address,
                       body="""
                           Here is the test message                               
                           """)

        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'LOGIN'

            template_values = {
                'greetings': greetings,
                'url': url,
                'url_linktext': url_linktext,
            }

            e_mail.address = self.request.get('emailAdd')

            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'about.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

            mail.send_mail(sender="Do Not Reply <myemail@address.com>",
                       to="Do Not Reply <myemail@address.com>",
                       subject=e_mail.address,
                       body="""
                           Here is the test message                               
                           """)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the user access MainPage, and you create a login link that redirects to MainPage() after the login/logout is complete.

However, after submitting the form, they get a login link that ends up redirecting back to Email_Signup().  If they click on that, they will attempt to login, then get redirected to Email_Signup(), which has no GET handler, so it just displays a blank page.